# Filtering a table with Ajax - Dropdown Selection - php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, json

In another post I was able to get some help with dynamically creating dropdowns using AJAX.

I have a table that displays (in an HTML table) all the information contained in a mySQL table - above that there are 3 dropdowns which pertain to particular rows of the table.  Right now I'm trying to get the table to 'refresh' with the data selected from the dropdowns (i.e. if user selects a dropdown - the table refreshes showing data filtered by their selection).

my client.php looks like this (this is what the user loads):

```
<script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  $(function () 
  {
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    //SEND HTTP REQUEST WITH AJAX INITIALLY
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    $.ajax({                                      
        url: 'api.php',   //the script to call to get data          
        data: "",   //insert url argumnets here to pass to api.php for example "id=5&parent=6"
        dataType: 'json',   //data format      
        success: function(response) //on recieve of reply     
        { //Do the following on Success 

            //Set the filtering for "Creative"
            var creatives = response.CREATIVE;
            for (var i in creatives)
            {
                var creative = creatives[i];
                var creativeID = creative[0];
                $('#creative-select').append("<option value=\""+creativeID+"\">"+creativeID+"</option>");
            }

            //Set the filtering for "Stations"
            var stations = response.STATION_NETWORK;
            for (var i in stations)
            {
                var station = stations[i];
                var stationID = station[0];
                $('#station-select').append("<option value=\""+stationID+"\">"+stationID+"</option>");
            }

            //Set the filtering for "Verticals"
            var verticals = response.VERTICAL;
            for (var i in verticals)
            {
                var vertical = verticals[i];
                var vertID = vertical[0];
                $('#vertical-select').append("<option value=\""+vertID+"\">"+vertID+"</option>");
            }

            //Set the Table Content  Initially
            var rows = response.rowdata;
            for (var i in rows)
            {
                var row = rows[i];
                var id = row[0];              //get id
                var station_network = row[1];       //get name
                var vertical = row[2];  //get vertical
                var creative = row[3]; //get creative
                var tolls= row[4];  //get tolls
                var states= row[5];  //get states
                var date_range= row[6];  //get date_range
                var week= row[7];  //get week
                var ordered= row[8];  //get ordered
                var credits= row[9];  //get credits
                var credit_totals= row[10];  //get credit_totals
                var not_used= row[11];
                var cleared= row[12];
                var total_uniques= row[13];
                var cleared_each_unique= row[14];
                var total_unique_connect= row[15];
                var cleared_each_unique_connect= row[16];
                var unique_connect_8am_to_8pm= row[17];
                var cleared_each_8am_to_8pm= row[18];
                var calls_over_10= row[19];
                var calls_over_10_pct= row[20];

                //TABLES (ALTERNATING ROWS)
                if (id % 2 == 0)
                {
                    $('#output').append("<tr id=\"evenrow\"> <td>"+id+"</td><td>"+station_network+"</td><td>"+vertical+"</td><td>"+creative+"</td><td>"+tolls+"</td><td>"+states+"</td><td>"+date_range+"</td><td>"+week+"</td><td>"+ordered+"</td><td>"+credits+"</td><td>"+credit_totals+"</td><td>"+not_used+"</td><td>"+cleared+"</td><td>"+total_uniques+"</td><td>"+cleared_each_unique+"</td><td>"+total_unique_connect+"</td><td>"+cleared_each_unique_connect+"</td><td>"+unique_connect_8am_to_8pm+"</td><td>"+cleared_each_8am_to_8pm+"</td><td>"+calls_over_10+"</td><td>"+calls_over_10_pct+"</td></tr>");
                } else {
                    $('#output').append("<tr id=\"oddrow\"> <td>"+id+"</td><td>"+station_network+"</td><td>"+vertical+"</td><td>"+creative+"</td><td>"+tolls+"</td><td>"+states+"</td><td>"+date_range+"</td><td>"+week+"</td><td>"+ordered+"</td><td>"+credits+"</td><td>"+credit_totals+"</td><td>"+not_used+"</td><td>"+cleared+"</td><td>"+total_uniques+"</td><td>"+cleared_each_unique+"</td><td>"+total_unique_connect+"</td><td>"+cleared_each_unique_connect+"</td><td>"+unique_connect_8am_to_8pm+"</td><td>"+cleared_each_8am_to_8pm+"</td><td>"+calls_over_10+"</td><td>"+calls_over_10_pct+"</td></tr>");
                }

            } // End of 'for' loop for the table data

        }  //End of 'do this on success'
    }); //End of AJAX call
  }); //End of Function

function showCreative (creativeVal) 
  {
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    //Send the Creative filter criteria
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    $.ajax({                                      
        url: 'api.php',   //the script to call to get data          
        data: "creative="+creativeVal,   //insert url argumnets here to pass to api.php for example "id=5&parent=6"
        dataType: 'json',   //data format      
        success: function(response) //on recieve of reply     
        { //Do the following on Success   
        alert ("this never fires!");

        } //end of on success
    }); //End Ajax call
}; //End Creative Function  

  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h2> Media Call Reports </h2>
  <h3>Media Analysis: </h3>
  <div id="instruction">Select how you would like the data selected using the dropdowns below</div>

<!--DROPDOWNS-->
 <div id="dropdowns">

    <div id="creativesel">
    Creative -  
    <select name="creative-select" id="creative-select" onChange ="showCreative(this.value);">
        <option value="all">All</option>
    </select>
    </div> 

    <div id="stationsel">
    Station - 
    <select name="station-select" id="station-select" onChange ="showStation(this.value)">
        <option value="all">All</option>
    </select>
    </div>

     <div id="verticalsel">
    Vertical - 
    <select name="vertical-select" id="vertical-select" onChange ="showVertical(this.value)">
        <option value="all">All</option>
    </select>
    </div>

</div> <!--Dropdowns ending-->

 <!--TABLE BEGINNING - TABLE HEADER ROW--> 
<table id="output">
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Station_Network</th>
<th>Vertical</th>
<th>Creative</th>
<th>Tolls</th>
<th>States</th>
<th>Date Range</th>
<th>Week</th>
<th>Ordered</th>
<th>Credits</th>
<th>Credits Totals</th>
<th>Not Used</th>
<th>Cleared</th>
<th>Total Uniques</th>
<th>Cleared Each Unique</th>
<th>Total Unique Connect</th>
<th>Cleared Each Unique Connect</th>
<th>Unique Connect 8am - 8pm</th>
<th>Cleared Unique 8am - 8pm</th>
<th>Calls over 10 Min</th>
<th>Calls over 10 Min %</th>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

What I currently have in my api.php looks like this:

```
<?php 
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Connect to DB
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  include 'DB.php';
  $con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass) ;
  $dbs = mysql_select_db($databaseName, $con);

  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Initial Page Load - get data from DB
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------  
  //Dropdown Filter Function
  function dropdownFilter($filterColumn)
  {
  global $finalarray;
  $filterSQL = "SELECT $filterColumn FROM media_analysis GROUP BY $filterColumn";
  $filterResult = mysql_query($filterSQL);
  $filterColumnData = array();
  while ($filterRow = mysql_fetch_row($filterResult)) 
      {
        $filterColumnData[] = $filterRow;
      }  
    $finalarray[$filterColumn] = $filterColumnData;
  }
    //Dropdown for Stations
    dropdownFilter("STATION_NETWORK");
    //Dropdown for Verticals
    dropdownFilter("VERTICAL");
    //Dropdown for Creative
    dropdownFilter("CREATIVE");

    //Rows of table-data in media-analysis
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName");   //Initial Query
    $data = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result) )
        {
        $data[] = $row;
        }   
    $finalarray['rowdata'] = $data;

//----------------------------------------------
//AFTER USER SELECTS FILTERS - IF ANY SELECTED
//----------------------------------------------
  //Get variables from subsequent calls in URL if any
if (isset($_GET['creative']) and !empty($_GET['creative'])) 
    { 
    $creativeFilter = $_GET['creative'];
    echo $creativeFilter;
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE CREATIVE = '$creativeFilter'");   
    $data = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result) )
        {
        $data[] = $row;
        }   
    $finalarray['rowdata'] = $data;
    }
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // 3) echo result as json 
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  echo json_encode($finalarray);
?>
```

The initial load works fine - the table is created and so are the dropdown selections.
Right now I'm just trying to get the 'creative' dropdown to work (hence why I'm focused on that).

When the user selects something from the creative dropdown - I see the AJAX call to the api.php with the appropriate addition (api.php?creative="whatever_user_selected") and the response comes back with all the correct data in the array (I can see it in the console) - but the table never updates.

Where do I need to put the code to update that table?  What's the best way to go about getting that updated??

I'm a noob at this and there's a lot of tutorials around - each one specifying something different to do - so I've been on here looking but unable to find something similar.

All help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your data part should look more like this:

```
data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
```

or

```
data: { creative: creativeVal }
```

Comment: That worked to help with the issue.  The other issue is that I had an echo in my php - so the response wasn't in json format >.<  Doh!  It's the little things - ugh!  Thank you!!